# how can i get term id of a page in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

if i am browsing a page of taxonomy in drupal, is there a way to get term-id of this page??
ex:

```
 
select * from term_data limit 2;

+-----+-----+--------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+------+  
| tid | vid | name                     | description | weight | language | trid |  
+-----+-----+--------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+------+  
|  24 |   1 | Central African Republic |             |      0 | en       |    0 |  
|  26 |   1 | Cyprus                   |             |      0 | en       |    0 |  
+-----+-----+--------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+------+
```

if i browse the page of Cyprus, how can i get its tid??

Comment: What do you mean by browsing the page of Cyprus? Give the url, please. Because basically a taxonomy page looks like http://example.com/taxonomy/term/3. Here you can get term-id by arg(2) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks...
i got the answer, it is `arg(2)`

- arg(0) ==> returns "taxonomy"
- arg(1) ==> returns "term"
- arg(2) ==> returns tid

in other words

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' &&  is_numeric(arg(2))) {
  return arg(2);
} 
else 
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: It may be safer to add an `arg(1) == 'term'` in that too. You never know what other taxonomy/foo/somenumber pages there may be. Also, it is considered good coding practice to always return the same *type*, so in your case `else { return 0; }` to always return an integer.